# Why is my Axios get request getting the entire array instead row associated with the param I pass in?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am using Axios requests to retrieve data from MySQL with an express server in between.
I have an API route of `'http://localhost:3001/find'` which displays the following json when accessed:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"book title 1","author":"book author 1",},
{"id":2,"title":"book title 2","author":"book author 2"}]
```

I am trying to retrieve the singular row with the id of 1, so am doing this get request:

```
  const searchMe = () => {
  Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/find', {
    params: {
      "id": "1"
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

However when I console log the response I get both rows instead of just the one. Is is possible the param isn't getting read properly or something?

EDIT: Here is the code in my express server for handling the 'find' request:

```
app.get('/find', (req, res)=>{

    const sqlInsert = "SELECT * FROM songs;"
    db.query(sqlInsert, (err, result)=> {
        res.send(result)
        // console.log(result);
    })
});
```

I know it definitely works because it is returning the data.

Comment: Would it be possible to view the code on the express server, please?

Comment: Yes of course: 

`const db = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'music_player'
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors());
// app.use(express.json());

app.get("/get", (req, res)=> {
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM songs;"
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('running on port 3001');
});` (apologies for bad formatting)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I mean the code to handle the /find request.

Comment: could you also include it in your original post (just edit it) to make it easier to read

Comment: I've added it above, is this what you're looking for? :)